# Only for $expand - member is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a problem with `$expand` clause:
This works -> `api/Components('XYZ')/Childs`
This doesn't -> `api/Components('XYZ')?$expand=Childs`

I have used EntityFramework(6.1.3) to map views in the database (read-only) and then created OData v3 controllers based on EF entities. It works great for most tables but problem appears when relation between entities isn't based on navigation property but LINQ query.
Here is code example:

```
public class ComponentsController : ODataController
{
....
  [EnableQuery]
  public IQueryable<Component> GetChilds([FromODataUri] string key)
  {
    var id = db.Components.First(c => c.Id == key).Identity;
    return db.ChildComponents.Where(cc => cc.Identity == id).Select(cc => cc.Component);
  }
```

What I cannot understand is why I cannot use `$expand=Childs` when `(...)/Childs` works fine?

## EDIT1:

Here is $metadata - navigation property "Users" works with $expand but "Childs" don't:

```
<EntityType Name="Component">
  <Key>
    <PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
  </Key>
  <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="Type" Type="Edm.String"/>
  <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String"/>
  <Property Name="Identity" Type="Edm.String"/>
  <NavigationProperty Name="Users" Relationship="HostingDb.Pandora.HostingDb_Pandora_Component_Users_HostingDb_Pandora_ComponentUser_UsersPartner" ToRole="Users" FromRole="UsersPartner"/>
  <NavigationProperty Name="Childs" Relationship="HostingDb.Pandora.HostingDb_Pandora_Component_Childs_HostingDb_Pandora_Component_ChildsPartner" ToRole="Childs" FromRole="ChildsPartner"/>
</EntityType>
<Association Name="HostingDb_Pandora_Component_Users_HostingDb_Pandora_ComponentUser_UsersPartner">
  <End Type="HostingDb.Pandora.ComponentUser" Role="Users" Multiplicity="*"/>
  <End Type="HostingDb.Pandora.Component" Role="UsersPartner" Multiplicity="0..1"/>
</Association>
<Association Name="HostingDb_Pandora_Component_Childs_HostingDb_Pandora_Component_ChildsPartner">
  <End Type="HostingDb.Pandora.Component" Role="Childs" Multiplicity="*"/>
  <End Type="HostingDb.Pandora.Component" Role="ChildsPartner" Multiplicity="0..1"/>
</Association>
```

Comment: It's weird that $expand is supported already. Would you please show the metadata?

Comment: @SamXu I have added metadata

Comment: use using mvc api.... how are you consuming it, angularjs? ie what is calling GetChilds.... what does the js look like.

Comment: @Seabizkit, client site is not relevant because I get HTTP 500 server error `System.NotSupportedException: The specified type member 'Childs' is not supported in LINQ to Entities...`

I don't use any automated client - I type query url myself and just test it on my browser.

Comment: @micmax93 if you say so.... to me api/Components('XYZ')?$expand=Childs is very much how you pass it to the api, i get what you are saying tho... but i believe its the combination of both but you seem to know best.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN NOT expect the `GetChilds(string)` be invoked for the request

```
api/Components('XYZ')?$expand=Childs
```

otherwise, the real method should be invoked in the controller is `Get(string)` for the above request.

On the other side,`GetChilds(string)` is only used for `api/Components('XYZ')/Childs`.

I wrote a sample project to test. you can refer it [here](https://github.com/xuzhg/WebApiSample/tree/master/ExpandTestInV3) to understand the routing for odata.  Thanks.